# Use literal (*) in grep pattern within shell script

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to evaluate a `grep` expression inside of a shell script, and that grep uses a literal asterisk (*), but that asterisk appears to be expanded by my bash instead of remaining a literal asterisk:

```
branch_description=$(git branch --list -vv | grep "^\*")
```

What can I do to run `grep` in this context and let it receive a literal asterisk in its `PATTERN` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that bash is interpreting the `\` and stripping it away, because it's inside double quotes.  Changing to

```
branch_description=$(git branch --list -vv | grep '^\*')
```

will do what you want.  See the section on QUOTING in the bash manual.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use the ascii octal code :

```
branch_description=$(git branch --list -vv | grep "^\052")
```

See

```
man 7 ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quote in grep to avoid expansion of `*` by shell:

```
branch_description=$(git branch --list -vv | grep '^\*')
```