# grep mistaking pattern for file?

Tags: grep, gnuwin32

```
cat file.txt | grep -x "\d*"
grep: \Documents and Settings: Is a directory
```

I want to search `file.txt` for any lines that are numbers only but grep seems to be viewing `\d*` as a wildcard for files and not the pattern. How can I specify that it's the pattern and it should use stdin for what to grep over?

The file is full of lines of datetime stamps, some end with a letter, some don't.

```
20140110122200
20131208041510M
...
```

I'm trying to only get the lines that don't end in a letter.

EDIT: I've also tried setting the filename instead of piping it with cat. Not much different.

```
C:\long\path>grep -ex "\d*" -f file.txt
grep: \Dell: Is a directory
grep: \Documents and Settings: Is a directory
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if the manpages applied to gnuwin packages. Still, using `-e` or setting the filename to `-` makes no difference

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051959/use-literal-in-grep-pattern-within-shell-script

Comment: @Jotne Does that apply to windows? I thought double quote vs single quote rules for expansion where just *nix.

Comment: Option `-e` tells `grep` to use the following text as pattern. When using `-e` with any other options, care must be taken. In your case, option `-x` was treated as the pattern to use thus the command is evaluated as `grep -e x "\d*"`. What you wanted is grep -xe "\d*".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `cat` to pass the file to grep? Why not just give grep the filename directly?

```
grep -x '\d*' file.txt
```

I think the actual problem you're seeing is that the `*` wildcard is being expanded. That's why grep is giving you errors that mention actual directories (beginning with 'd') on your system.

Comment: How can I prevent the expansion from happening?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Are you running the commands from a normal windows command prompt (cmd.exe)? (ie, not some other shell like msys, cygwin or powershell)

Comment: Yes just a plain cmd.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Good question... I wish I knew the answer.