# Prevent globbing in command output bash

Tags: bash, git, github, travis-ci

This is my script, and it works fine locally. However, travis gives me `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 11`, which would be the beginning B in BRANCH#??.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH="$(git branch | grep '^\*')"
BRANCH="${BRANCH#??}"
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "Github Actions", "content": "**Branch:** `'$BRANCH'`"}' "$WEBHOOK"
```

What I'm trying to achieve: I'm trying to send a webhook message with the name of the current branch from travis, which I'm using in combination with another curl script in order to upload the build output, separately.

Unfortunately somehow there's an issue with globbing in the shell that travis uses.

Edit: echoing branch on travis gets me `'(HEAD detached at 2743a34)'`, it appears to checkout the commit.

Edit 2: solved, using `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` to get the branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use literal (\*) in grep pattern within shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051959/use-literal-in-grep-pattern-within-shell-script)

Comment: A more robust way to get the current branch name would be something like `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`, no potential globs involved.

Comment: @oguzismail, no, I still have the same issue. Edited my post.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that doesn't seem to work on travis for some reason, while it did locally.

Comment: What is the value of `BRANCH` when you run the code? Note that you left its expansion unquoted; that isn't recommended. (Also, the backticks aren't legal JSON syntax. I recommend using `jq` or the like to generate the JSON blob: `... -d "$(jq -n --arg b "$BRANCH" '{..., content: "**Branch:** \($b)"}')" ...`.)

Comment: I found the issue, travis checks out the commit itself. `'(HEAD detached at 2743a34)'` is what echoing branch gets

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer instead of as an edit to the question.